# Java Spring : Iterating over JSON/XML - MultipartFile

Tags: java, json, xml, spring

I created a Springapplication with a little Userinterface in HTML. The user can select one file (he will have to select a XML or JSON-File) an the program is iterating over the file, filtering and uses the neccessary information.

I can read the file and pass it to the program. I defined it as a MultipartFile:

```html
<form method="POST" action="/submit-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br><br>

    <label for="email">E-Mail:</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email"><br><br>

    <label for="password">Passwort:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password"><br><br>
    <input type="file" name="file"><br><br>
    <button type="submit">Senden</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The Java Code looks like this:

```Java
    @PostMapping("/submit-form")
    public String submitForm(@RequestParam("name") String name,
                             @RequestParam("email") String email,
                             @RequestParam("password") String password,
                             @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        System.out.println("Name: " + name);
        System.out.println("E-Mail: " + email);
        System.out.println("Passwort: " + password);
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {

                String fileContent = new String(file.getBytes());
                System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());

                return "upload-success"; 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return "form-success"; 
    }
```

Here is an example of a JSON-File:

```JSON
{
  "id": 12345,
  "name": "Example JSON",
  "description": "A complex JSON file example",
  "created_at": "2023-06-20T12:00:00Z",
  "categories": ["category1", "category2", "category3"],
  "tags": ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"],
  "data": {
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "value2",
    "field3": 42
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Item 1",
      "quantity": 5,
      "price": 10.99,
      "description": "Description of item 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Item 2",
      "quantity": 3,
      "price": 7.99,
      "description": "Description of item 2"
    }
    // ... (more items)
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "username": "user1",
      "email": "user1@example.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "username": "user2",
      "email": "user2@example.com"
    }
    // ... (more users)
  ],
  "settings": {
    "theme": "dark",
    "notifications": true,
    "language": "en"
  },
  "meta": {
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "John Doe"
  }
  // ... (more properties)
}
```

My question is now:

Could you give me a guideline whats the best way to use the MultipartFile as Input and saving the values to an Object that i can easily access the data? I´m also not sure, if its better to use JSON or XML (have the data in both structures)? And maybe my first attempt isn´t a good way to handle it and you got a better solution for me.

Thx and kind regards!
Da_Pusti

Answer (score 0):

In my case I created a dto class which implements Serializable and it has the same fields as UploadedMultipartFile which itself is an implemaentation of MultipartFile, so I receive the file as JSON and then I convert it to an extended class of UploadedMultipartFile.

So this is my dto which I use as the input in the Controller

```
import lombok.*;    
import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class UploadedMultipartFileDto implements Serializable {

    private byte[] bytes;
    private String contentType;
    private String formParameterName;
    private String originalFilename;
}
```

And this is the Model which extends UploadedMultipartFile

```
import org.springframework.integration.http.multipart.UploadedMultipartFile;


public class ThunderUploadedMultipartFile extends UploadedMultipartFile {

    public ThunderUploadedMultipartFile(byte[] bytes, String contentType, String formParameterName, String originalFilename) {
        super(bytes, contentType, formParameterName, originalFilename);
    }
}
```

Before saving the file, I convert dto to model with MapStruct like this

```
    ThunderUploadedMultipartFile file = uploadedMultipartFileMapper.toModel(fileDto);
    FileUploadUtil.saveFile(file);
```

Comment: Hi Azadi, thank you for your answer. I´m not very sure, how i can use this now? Should i replace my MultipartFile for your ThunderUploadedMultipartFile?

Comment: Hi Da_Pusti. I don't know if your code works or if you have any problem in your work, but my problem was that when using MultipartFile as the input like yours, the filters for authentication didn't work and the endpoint was reached without any authentication. I also had some problems with UploadedMultipartFile as endpoint input, so I created the class UploadedMultipartFileDto just like UploadedMultipartFile with the same fields which implements Serializable and will be serialized as JSON. This worked for me and the filters of authentication were doing well.

Comment: So replace UploadedMultipartFileDto with MultipartFile in method "submitForm" and check if your problem will be solved or not.